# Coefficients of Mystery Polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Let's play a game. I have a polynomial $f(x)$ which has nonnegative integer coefficients. You can ask me for the value of $f(n)$, where $n$ is a nonnegative integer. In how many $n$ can you determine the coefficients of my polynomial?

This problem isn't so bad. First you can ask for $f(1)$, which is greater than or equal to each individual coefficient of my polynomial. Then you can ask for $f(f(1))$ and express it in base $f(1)$, which works because we've already determined that $f(1)$ is at least as large as each coefficient, so at each digit there is no "bleed-over" into the next digit.

Quick example, just to confirm I'm not crazy:

$$f(x) = 2x^3 + 2x + 3$$
$$f(1) = 7$$
$$f(7) = 703$$
$$703_7 = 2023$$

My question is this: one of our assumptions is that $f$ has **nonnegative** coefficients. What happens if we relax this restraint to say the coefficients can be *any* integer?

My intuition is that we should still be able to guess the polynomial in finitely many steps, but we can't use the method outlined above because we have no guarantee $f(1)$ will be larger than each coefficient - in fact, $f(1)$ may be zero.

What happens if we relax the constraint to be **nonnegative rational** coefficients, instead?

Comment: An intermediate version is where the coefficients are integers greater than or equal to $-1$:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3099594/finding-coefficients-of-a-polynomial-with-minimal-queries

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to determine $f$ in finitely many queries if its coefficients are allowed to be arbitrary integers.  Indeed, suppose you have queried the values of $f(n_1),\dots,f(n_k)$ so far.  Then the polynomial $g(x)=f(x)+(x-n_1)(x-n_2)\dots(x-n_k)$ is another polynomial with integer coefficients with $g(n_1)=f(n_1),\dots,g(n_k)=f(n_k)$.  So, you cannot yet determine $f$ uniquely.

Comment: Also, it seems this approach (with a small fix) works even if you are allowed to query $f(x)$ for rational (not just integral) $x$.

Comment: Yeah, you can still add a polynomial that vanishes at all those values of $x$.  In fact, this even works if $x$ can be algebraic.

Answer (score 1):

There is a result in

> Bettina Richmond (2010) On a Perplexing Polynomial Puzzle, The College Mathematics Journal, 41:5, 400-403, DOI: [10.4169/074683410X522017](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.4169/074683410X522017)

that definitively answers the negative integer coefficients case.

A preprepint is also available [here](https://csclub.uwaterloo.ca/%7En3parikh/On%20a%20Perplexing%20Polynomial%20Puzzle.pdf).

Summary below:

> It seems rather surprising that any given polynomial $p(x)$ with nonnegative integer coefficients can be determined by just the two values $p(1)$ and
> $p(a)$, where a is any integer greater than $p(1)$. This result has become known
> as a “perplexing polynomial puzzle” in [2, 3]. Here, we address the natural
> question of what might be required to determine a polynomial with integer
> coefficients, if the condition that the coefficients be nonnegative is removed.
>
> Let us analyze the original puzzle. Requiring that $p(x) = c_0 + c_1 x +
> \cdots + c_nx^n$ has nonnegative integer coefficients gives zero as a lower bound
> and $p(1) = c_0 + c_1 + \cdots + c_n$ as an upper bound for the coefficients. Then
> if $a > p(1)$, writing $p(a)$ as $c_0 + c_1 a + \cdots + c_n a^n$ gives the unique base $a$
> representation of $p(a)$, so the nonnegative integer coefficients $c0, c1, \cdots , cn$ of
> $p(x)$ are completely determined by $p(a)$. The coefficients of $p(x)$, which serve
> as the base a digits, must fall in the appropriate set $\{0, 1, . . . , a − 1\}$, so we
> must choose $a$ to be an upper bound of the coefficients.
>
> If we allow negative coefficients and find a bound $b$ on the coefficients
> so that $−b \le c_i \le b$ for all $i$, then we wonder whether the coefficients
> are uniquely determined by the value of $p(a) = c_0 + c_1 a + \cdots + c_n a^n$
> for
> a suitable choice of $a$. Theorem 3 answers this question affirmatively, giving $a = 2b + 1$ as a suitable choice. In effect, we ask whether $p(a)$ has
> a unique base $a$ representation if the digits $c_i$ assume values from the set
> $\{−b, −b + 1, \cdots , 0, \cdots , b − 1, b\}$. Theorem 2 confirms the existence of such a
> representation.